# Add html element jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to copy a textarea in my html code by clicking a button that adds it to the same container of the first textarea.

My code is:

```
$("#note_adder").click(function(){$("#p_note").clone().append('note_id')});
```

- Button's id is `note_adder`
- Textarea's id is `p_note`
- Container's id is `note_id`

I also want to change the name attribute of the newly created textarea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things: you need to use `appendTo`, and you need a `#` in front of `note_id`.

```
$('#note_adder').click(function () {
    var counter = $('[id^="p_note"]').length;
    $('#p_note').clone().attr({
        id: 'p_note_' + counter,
        name: 'p_note_' + counter
    }).appendTo('#note_id');
});
```

I also changed the `id` of the cloned textarea since IDs should be unique. With each successive click, it should produce new textareas with names and ids of:

- p_note_1
- p_note_2
- etc...

Here's a demo borrowed from [Shadow Wizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662630/add-html-element-jquery/5662655#5662655): http://jsfiddle.net/cq9Hq/2/.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to change the ID, but what when button clicked twice? :)

Comment: @Shadow, aha good point! Let me work on it... How is that now?

Comment: Simple matter of counter.. feel free to use my below test case. :)

Answer (score 3):

Need to be `appendTo`:

```
$("#note_adder").click(function(){$("#p_note").clone().appendTo('#note_id')});
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/cq9Hq/

Updated with Box9 better approach: http://jsfiddle.net/cq9Hq/1/

Comment: thanks for mentioning the appendTo mistake i didn't notice it and for live test :)

Comment: @Star cheers, as Box9 answer is the same as mine and better (same ID is really bad idea) the only reason I leave my answer is for the test case.